# What kind of data type can be rounded off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently trying to round off a float number but i get an error message like: undefined method round_to for float 16.666667.. and my code for rounding off is

```
  option = [keys[count],    (((o.poll_votes.count.to_f)/@general_poll.poll_votes.count.to_f)*100).round_to(1)]
```

And what suprises me the most is that i have used this code at several places and is working just fine..but now is giving me errors.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

the method round_to does not exist anywhere in ruby core. Most likely this functionality was included in a library you were using before but have not required it in your current project. After a quick search it looks like this functionality is included in the Ruby Facets library.

```
gem install facets
```

Check this article to add this functionality yourself: http://www.hans-eric.com/code-samples/ruby-floating-point-round-off/

**FTA:**

With a little monkey patching we can add custom round off methods to the Float class.

```
class Float
  def round_to(x)
    (self * 10**x).round.to_f / 10**x
  end

  def ceil_to(x)
    (self * 10**x).ceil.to_f / 10**x
  end

  def floor_to(x)
    (self * 10**x).floor.to_f / 10**x
  end
end
```

------------------ snip 8<-------------------

Comment: I have realized that there was nothing in the library, can you please just explain in detail how i can use this monkey patching?

anyway thanks for the response.

Comment: Monkey patching is just a way of saying appending methods to an already defined class. If you add this code to your project it will extend Float and methods will be available.

I checked out the facets gem and it seems they have 2 methods round_to and round_at. round_at mimics the code posted above.. sorry if this caused confusion.

Comment: In my application I had to remove the `.to_f` in line 3 after `(self * 10**x).round` to avoid nasty-looking residual digits when I `round_to(5)` eg. `Slope=-0.4123800000000001`